# Why do tidal forces not violate conservation of energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, tidal-effect, satellites

Europa is an example of a satellite which is heated by tidal forces. The orbit is constant, so how is energy conserved on Europa?

Comment: Why do you think the orbit will be constant?

Comment: Or, put slightly differently, what changes as tidal forces are applied to the body?

Comment: What part of the phenomena do you expect to be violating energy conservation?  The force applied to the satellite is not uniform throughout...

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142435/ . It's not the same question, but you may find that it answers your underlying question. The short version is that *"The orbit is constant"* isn't actually true (but then neither is the orbit of Luna around Earth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the title forces will cause the object in this case the moon to have a circular orbit. The closer it gets to a perfectly circular orbit the less title forces there are or at least more constant.

Comment: Which one it is, less or more constant? Circular orbits have tidal forces at least.